# PHP - Hide elements when the statement is true

Tags: php, hide, element

I have this code to hide elements but first part is hide and the second part is showing always not matter if i login like user or administrator. I don't understand what is wrong there...

I want when i login like user to show first dropdown-content and when i login like administrator to show the second dropdown-content but when i login like user or administrator is show only the second dropdown-content.

Code:

```html
<?php
if($parola == $data['parola'] && $data['admin'] == '0'){?>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn"><?php echo $_SESSION['mail']; ?></button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="adauga.php">Adauga anunt</a>
    <a href="anunturi.php">Anunturile mele</a>
    <a href="edit.php">Editeaza profil</a>
 <a href="logout.php">Delogeaza-te</a>
  </div>
</div> 
<?php } else { ?>  
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn"><?php echo $_SESSION['mail']; ?></button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="/admin/index.php">Control Panel</a>
 <a href="logout.php">Delogeaza-te</a>
  </div>
</div> 
<?php } ?>
```

The login for user, administrator and banned users.

```html
<?php
 require 'config.php';
 if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
  $errMsg = '';
  // Get data from FORM
  $mail = $_POST['mail'];
  $parola = $_POST['parola'];
  if($mail == '')
   $errMsg = 'Introduceti adresa de mail.';
  if($parola == '')
   $errMsg = 'Introduceti parola.';
  if($errMsg == '') {
   try {
    $stmt = $connect->prepare('SELECT mail, parola, admin, banned FROM acc_table WHERE mail = :mail');  
    $stmt->execute(array(
     ':mail' => $mail
     ));
    $data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if($data == false){
     $errMsg = "Contul asociat cu mail-ul $mail nu a fost gasit.";
    }
    else {
     if($parola == $data['parola'] and $data['admin'] == '1') {
      $_SESSION['mail'] = $data['mail'];
      $_SESSION['parola'] = $data['parola'];
      $_SESSION['admin'] = $data['admin'];
      header('Location: ../admin/index.php');
      exit;
     }
     else
      $errMsg = 'Parola nu este buna.';
    }
    
     if($parola == $data['parola'] and $data['banned'] == '1') {
      $_SESSION['mail'] = $data['mail'];
      $_SESSION['parola'] = $data['parola'];
      $_SESSION['banned'] = $data['banned'];
      header('Location: ban.html');
      exit;
     }
     else
      $errMsg = 'Parola nu este buna.';
     
     if($parola == $data['parola'] and $data['admin'] == '0') {
      $_SESSION['mail'] = $data['mail'];
      $_SESSION['parola'] = $data['parola'];
      $_SESSION['admin'] = $data['admin'];
      header('Location: profile.php');
      exit;
     }
     else
      $errMsg = 'Parola nu este buna.';
         
   }
   catch(PDOException $e) {
    $errMsg = $e->getMessage();
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Your question is is unclear....I'd recommend posting the rest of your PHP code

Comment: I'd also recommend to try using one `if` statement at a time so try `<?php if ($parola == $data['parola']) { ?>` to see if it works, then erase it and try `<?php if ($data['admin'] == '0') { ?>` and see which statement is giving you the issue and you can sort it out from there

Comment: Oke. Thanks for answer. I will come with a feedback.

Comment: I just try it. With `<?php if ($parola == $data['parola']) { ?>` it works but with `<?php if ($data['admin'] == '0') { ?>` is not working.

Comment: Okay so that means `admin` is not set to `0`. It's set as something else or not set at all. Where's the rest of your PHP code? Update your original post with the rest of your PHP code.so we can better help

Comment: Done. The redirect pages work fine but to hide the elements doesn't.

Comment: You have several errors in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get a solution for my problem.

He didn't work with header redirect but work with JavaScript. 
I use to force the user to stay on the page with:

```html
<?php
 if(['admin'] == '1')?>
  <script>
  window.location = 'admin/index.php';
  </script>
```

Thanks all for your contribution to help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code to see if this works for you.

If this doesn't work let me know what error you get.

```
<?php
require 'config.php';

if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

    $errMsg = '';
    // Get data from FORM
    $mail = $_POST['mail'];
    $parola = $_POST['parola'];
    if ($mail == '') {
        $errMsg = 'Introduceti adresa de mail.';
    } else if ($parola == '') {
        $errMsg = 'Introduceti parola.';
    } else {
        if ($errMsg == '') {
            try {
                $stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT mail, parola, admin, banned FROM acc_table WHERE mail = :mail");
                $stmt->bindParam(':mail', $var_mail);
                $var_mail = $_POST['mail'];
                $stmt->execute();
                if ($data = $stmt->fetch()) {
                    if ($parola == $data['parola'] and $data['admin'] == '0') {
                        $_SESSION['mail'] = $data['mail'];
                        $_SESSION['parola'] = $data['parola'];
                        $_SESSION['admin'] = $data['admin'];
                        header('Location: profile.php');
                        exit;
                    } else if ($parola == $data['parola'] && $data['admin'] == '1') {
                        $_SESSION['mail'] = $data['mail'];
                        $_SESSION['parola'] = $data['parola'];
                        $_SESSION['admin'] = $data['admin'];
                        header('Location: ../admin/index.php');
                        exit;
                    } else if ($parola == $data['parola'] && $data['banned'] == '1') {
                        $_SESSION['mail'] = $data['mail'];
                        $_SESSION['parola'] = $data['parola'];
                        $_SESSION['banned'] = $data['banned'];
                        header('Location: ban.html');
                        exit;
                    } else {
                        $errMsg = 'Parola nu este buna.';
                    }
                } else {
                    $errMsg = "Contul asociat cu mail-ul ".$var_mail." nu a fost gasit.";
                }
            }
            catch(PDOException $e) {
                $errMsg = $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works but i can't force the user to stay in that redirect page. 
Example: When i login with a banned user he redirect me to 'ban.html' but when i back he goes to website and can make everything like a normal user.

Answer (score 0):

Put the if condition like this :-

```
if($data['admin'] === '0'){
    //The rest code runs here
}
```

Let me know if this works or not .